# Encrypt non sensitive client side data and decrypt on server side

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps

We are using Google maps geocoder server side to get Latitude and Longitude for an address but need to move away from that and geocode on the client side to avoid API limits.

So in the form we have 3 hidden values: `address`, `lat`, `lon`.

Is there a way I can change this to one encrypted form field that I can decrypt in PHP?

The issue is that someone could tamper with the address and then we have a lat and long that point at the wrong place.

Is there a way of guaranteeing that the user is not tampering with the field?

Comment: Usually the reason for doing the geocoding in the client is to allow the user to correct erroneous results, not to keep them from doing that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can change this to one encrypted form field that I can decrypt in PHP?

Yes … but since you are generating the data on the client in the first place, the unencrypted version will still be available to the user … as will everything they need to encrypt it, so it isn't worth the effort.

> Is there a way of guaranteeing that the user is not tampering with the field?

No.